# Node.js Packaged Modules security concern

Tags: node.js, npm

I am learning Node.js and I understand it has been trusted by big companies. But for many web developers including me I don’t have resources or even full knowledge to do security auditing on every module I install.

Are all the modules listed in NPM inspected or audited?

What is the best practice in terms of security when installing new modules from NPM?

Comment: Go to the NPM page and look at reviews.

Comment: @Scimonster That's not really a security audit, though. A package could be acting nice on the surface and provide useful functionality but still be pwning you somewhere in a cryptically written parts of its innards that no one looks at. With the nice install hooks that npm provides, I don't even need to start using the package for it to do something like start a keylogger, wait till I run sudo, and from thence, sky is the limit.